# How to sort multiple columns under new columns based on row values from another column within the same dataframe pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, merge, multiple-columns

This is my dataset:

| Name | India | Japan | USA | France | Italy | Continent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Foo | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | Asia |
| Baz | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | N.America |
| Bob | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | Europe |

How I want the result to look like:

```
|      |  Asia     | N. America |   Europe       |
| Name |India|Japan|    USA     | France | Italy |
|------|-----|-----|------------|--------|-------|
| Foo  |  1  |  1  |     0      |   0    |  0    |         
| Baz  |  0  |  0  |     1      |   0    |  0    |       
| Bob  |  0  |  0  |     0      |   1    |  1    |
```

Can't seem to figure this out, any help is appreciated :')

Answer (score 0):

One option with `stack`/`unstack`:

```
(df.set_index(['Name', 'Continent'])
   .replace({0: np.nan}).stack()
   .unstack(['Continent', -1], fill_value=0)
   .convert_dtypes()
)
```

Another with `pivot_table`:

```
(df.pivot_table(index='Name', columns='Continent', fill_value=0)
   .loc(axis=1)[lambda d: d.eq(1).any()]
)
```

output:

```
Continent  Asia       N.America Europe      
          India Japan       USA France Italy
Name                                        
Baz           0     0         1      0     0
Bob           0     0         0      1     1
Foo           1     1         0      0     0
```